# Android NFC Transmit without Android Beam, mock like Google Wallet

Tags: android, nfc

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to emulate the functionality of Google Wallet. After my preliminary investigation, I have learned that Google Wallet does something called Card Emulation mode. In this mode, you can write NFC data like you would to an NFC card, only you can have callbacks on the card. Since Card Emulation Mode is locked down, I'm stuck in trying to find a way to emulate this functionality. I want to have a button that says "Tap to pay", then have a screen come up that says the payment information is waiting to be sent. Once the information is sent, the screen will disappear. All of this is mock and won't be sending any real or important data. This is basically for a mock display.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way to "activate" Card emulation is to use a custom rom. About the mock part -> if its mock, just use a connection over wifi or bluetooth?

Comment: Yeah. I'd love to simplify this by using some sort of intermediary server to say when a card is read or written, but where this "mock" app will be used, there will be no LAN connection, and WAN (cellular) I feel will be to latent.